# ReactJS - document.querySelectorAll() with lazy component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a problem with my React application.
When I try to retrieve a list of selectors, I am unable to retrieve the ones in the lazy component.

In my  component, my variable "length" only counts selectors of the  class.
She counts 6 instead of 7.

Can you help me solve my problem?

- ***App.js***

```
    import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
    import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    import AppFront from './AppFront';
    import Mouse from './component/Mouse';
    import './App.css';
    
    const LazyComponentTwo = lazy(() => import('./component/ComponentTwo'));
    
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Mouse />
          <Switch>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
              <Route exact path="/" component={AppFront} />
              <Route path="/component-two" component={LazyComponentTwo} />
            </Suspense>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

- ***AppFront.jsx***

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react';
     import ComponentOne from './component/ComponentOne';
    
    class AppFront extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="AppFront">
            <ComponentOne />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default AppFront;
```

- ***ComponentOne.jsx***

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    
    class ComponentOne extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="ComponentOne">
            <p className="text">Hello, this text contains a class name.</p>
            <p className="text">Hello, this text contains a class name.</p>
            <p className="text">Hello, this text contains a class name.</p>
            <p className="text">Hello, this text contains a class name.</p>
            <p className="text">Hello, this text contains a class name.</p>
            <p className="text">Hello, this text contains a class name.</p>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default ComponentOne;
```

- ***ComponentTwo.jsx***

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    
    class ComponentTwo extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="ComponentTwo">
            <p className="text">Hello, this text contains a class name.</p>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default ComponentTwo;
```

- ***Mouse.jsx***

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    
    class Mouse extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        const length = document.querySelectorAll(".text");
        console.log(length); // Output : 6, and not 7
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="Mouse">
    
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default Mouse;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that this would just be the expected behaviour in this case.

Because the ComponentTwo is displayed on a different route /component-two, and hence not loaded yet, the length of the array returned from the querySelectorAll should indeed be 6.

If in case you want that to be selected at the time of calling the componentDidMount(), you could try not lazy loading the component.

Comment: The problem is that if the component is not lazy, the application can become very cumbersome to load. There is no other solution please ?

Comment: Just like with any other situation, there are tradeoffs to lazy loading. If the component doesn't exist yet, I don't see why you would expect it to reflect in the length.

Comment: Okay, I get it, I'm going to have to change that.

Thank you